# Is it possible to disable a page when using PageView, Swiper or liquid_swiper?

Tags: flutter

I want to have the swiper effect in my app, I want to have 7 pages and move between the screens. I plan to have a `form` on every page.

For example, I am using Swiper package

```
                        Swiper(
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return pagesWizzard[index]; //my 7 pages
                          },
                          itemCount: pagesWizzard.length,
                          pagination: new SwiperPagination(
                              margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              builder: new DotSwiperPaginationBuilder(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  activeColor: Colors.blue)),
                        ),
```

[image]

If I completed the `form` on page 1, I want to be able to slide the screen to go to page 2, and if I want I can go back and so on. If I have not completed the `form` on page 1, I should not be able to move to page 2 and higher.

Currently in: `PageView, Swiper or liquid_swiper` I can't find how to disable a page or multiple pages.
I would like you to guide me on how to do this.

Another question, is it a good practice to put my forms inside these components that allow swiping to navigate between screens? I ask about the issue of forms rendering and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way on how to achieve this is passing a bool threw your form which checks if the formfields are filled in or not. If no, you prevent swiping to the next pages.

Using `PageView` with `NeverscrollableScrollPhysics()` and a `PageController` does the work for you.

```
// Outside build method
PageController controller = PageController();
// Inside build method
PageView(
  controller: controller,
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  children: <Widget>[
    // Add children
  ],
)
```

A good article for basic understanding of `PageController` can be found here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded

With `NeverscrollableScrollPhysics` you block the swiping. Now wrap your children with a `GestureDetector`, and on swiping right you will check if your bool is true or not. If yes you will navigate to the next page with the `PageController`.

Example for `GestureDetector`

```
    GestureDetector(onPanUpdate: (details) {
      if (details.delta.dx > 0 && formFilled == true) {
      pageController.jumpToPage(index);
        // swiping in right direction
      }

});
```